# How to delete subfolders and files from parent folders found in the variable of a bat script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, delete-file

What I'm trying to do is find all the folders named "temp" on local disk C and then delete all files and subfolders that are inside it, but I don't know how to delete it, I only managed to get to the part of finding all folders and put them in the variable, but I don't know the correct code to delete. Help.

```
@echo off
setlocal
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
for /d /r "c:\" %%i in (temp) do (
@if exist "%%i" (
@set _variable=%%i
@echo !_variable!
)
)
endlocal
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

cd /d "C:\" && for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('dir /s /b /a:d "temp"')do (
   echo\ Current Folder: "%%~i"
   echo\ RmDir /q /s "%%~i"
   echo\ MkDir "%%~i"
  )

%__APPDIR__%\Timeout.exe /t -1 & endlocal & goto :EOF
```

**1)** Go to the drive:

```bat
cd /d "C:\"
```

**2)** Use **`For /f`** with **`dir /s /b /a:d`** instead **`For /D /R`**

```bat
 for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('dir /s /b /a:d "temp"')do...
```

**3)** Don't need to delete the files in the target folder, just remove this folder and recreate it again...

```bat
RmDir /q /s "%%~i" && MkDir "%%~i\*"
```

---

- Outputs look like this:

```bat
Current Folder: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Temp"
rmdir /q /s "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Temp"
mkdir "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Temp\"
Current Folder: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\temp"
rmdir /q /s "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\temp"
mkdir "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\temp\"
Current Folder: "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp"
rmdir /q /s "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp"
mkdir "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\"
Current Folder: "C:\Users\All Users\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp"
rmdir /q /s "C:\Users\All Users\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp"
mkdir "C:\Users\All Users\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\"
Current Folder: "C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Temp"
rmdir /q /s "C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Temp"
mkdir "C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Temp\"
Current Folder: "C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Local\Temp"
rmdir /q /s "C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Local\Temp"
mkdir "C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Local\Temp\"
Current Folder: "C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Local\Intel\CUIPromotions\Temp"
rmdir /q /s "C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Local\Intel\CUIPromotions\Temp"
mkdir "C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Local\Intel\CUIPromotions\Temp\"
Current Folder: "C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Local\Packages\windows_ie_ac_001\AC\Temp"
rmdir /q /s "C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Local\Packages\windows_ie_ac_001\AC\Temp"
mkdir "C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Local\Packages\windows_ie_ac_001\AC\Temp\"
Current Folder: "C:\Windows\Temp"
rmdir /q /s "C:\Windows\Temp"
mkdir "C:\Windows\Temp\"
Current Folder: "C:\Windows\assembly\temp"
rmdir /q /s "C:\Windows\assembly\temp"
mkdir "C:\Windows\assembly\temp\"
mkdir "C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\Temp\"
Current Folder: "C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\Temp"
rmdir /q /s "C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\Temp"
mkdir "C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\Temp\"
Current Folder: "C:\Windows\WinSxS\Temp"
rmdir /q /s "C:\Windows\WinSxS\Temp"
mkdir "C:\Windows\WinSxS\Temp\"
```

---

- Verify in your test the outputs and for effective execution, remove **`echo`** in:

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

cd /d "C:\" && for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('dir /s /b /a:d "temp"')do (
   echo\ Current Folder: "%%~i"
   echo\ RmDir /q /s "%%~i"
   echo\ MkDir "%%~i"
  )

%__APPDIR__%\Timeout.exe /t -1 & endlocal & goto :EOF
```

---

- Or use this short option to suppress a possible error message for any folder in use or some other type of error

  ---

```bat
@echo off 

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion && cd /d "C:\"
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /s /b /a:d "temp"
')do 2>nul >nul (RmDir /q /s "%%~i" && MkDir "%%~i")
"%__APPDIR__%\Timout.exe" -1 & endlocal & goto :EOF
```

- And, of course, a slightly smaller option...

```bat
@echo off 

cd/d "C:\" & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('dir/s/b/a:d "temp"
')do 2>nul (RmDir /q /s "%%~i" && MD "%%~i")
"%__APPDIR__%\Timeout.exe" /t -1 && endlocal
```

---

**For command line help, you can use `/?`:**

```bat
RmDir /?, For /?, MkDir /?, Endlocal /?, SetLocal /?
```

**On the internet, you can get more help on:**

- **[For /f](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)**
- **[Endlocal](https://ss64.com/nt/endlocal.html)**
- **[Goto :EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37515901/where-does-goto-eof-return-to)**
- **[Timeout.exe](https://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html)**
- **[EnableDelayedExpansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028)**
- **[Conditional Execution || && ...](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)**